# How to create android client for Microsoft CRM 4.0?

Tags: java, android, crm

I would like to create simple android client to CRM. I would like to connect to CRM and download some data from it.
My question is:

- is there a tutorial for it?

Comment: which CRM your are going to use?

Comment: I guess the answer buried somewhere in this place http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681559.aspx

Comment: This is a poorly researched question, imo.

like many platforms, CRM has an SDK which even a brief look would reveal that it natively exposes metadata and business data via web services. 

your friend Google will readily tell you about where to find the CRM SDK if you ask nicely. look at that, and come back to SE when you have a specific issue that you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Forgot to mention before, Microsoft are apparently developing official CRM Mobile Apps - including the Android. Apparently it should be touching down Q4 2012. [See Release Guide.](http://crmpublish.blob.core.windows.net/docs/ReleasePreviewGuide.pdf)

Crm has a webservice api that you can use to query data.

You will probably want to read: [Developing Custom Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928396)

And then the web services Crm exposes:

1. [CrmService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151038)
2. [CrmDiscoveryService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151013)
3. [MetadataService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151047)

Comment: Good shout on the Q4 update (already +1'd tho)

Answer (score 0):

I think no, but if Microsoft CRM provide web-services for accecc to data you can use them.